# Dictionary / JSON issue using Python 2.7

Tags: python, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

I'm looking at scraping some data from Facebook using Python 2.7. My code basically augments by 1 changing the Facebook profile ID to then capture details returned by the page.

An example of the page I'm looking to capture the data from is graph.facebook.com/4.

Here's my code below:

```
import scraperwiki
import urlparse
import simplejson

source_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/"
profile_id = 1


while True:
    try:
        profile_id +=1
        profile_url = urlparse.urljoin(source_url, str(profile_id))
        results_json = simplejson.loads(scraperwiki.scrape(profile_url))
        for result in results_json['results']:
            print result
            data = {}
            data['id'] = result['id']
            data['name'] = result['name']
            data['first_name'] = result['first_name']
            data['last_name'] = result['last_name']
            data['link'] = result['link']
            data['username'] = result['username']
            data['gender'] = result['gender']
            data['locale'] = result['locale']
            print data['id'], data['name']
            scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys=['id'], data=data)
        #time.sleep(3)
    except:
        continue
        profile_id +=1
```

I am using the scraperwiki site to carry out this check but no data is printed back to console despite the line 'print data['id'], data['name'] *used just to check the code is working*

Any suggestions on what is wrong with this code? As said, for each returned profile, the unique data should be captured and printed to screen as well as populated into the sqlite database.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried printing `results_json`?

Comment: What happens when you don't swallow all the errors in your `try` block?

Comment: Bryan, the results of 'print results_json' immediately after this is as expected:
{'username': 'zuck', 'first_name': 'Mark', 'last_name': 'Zuckerberg', 'name': 'Mark Zuckerberg', 'locale': 'en_US', 'gender': 'male', 'link': 'http://www.facebook.com/zuck', 'id': '4'}

Comment: @Wilduck is exactly right. Any error above that line in the try block would be caught, which would cause there to be absolutely no output. While there are many possible errors it could be catching, perhaps the most likely is a `KeyError`

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of all of those `data['locale'] = result['locale']` lines, which are just copying a dictionary over key by key? Why not just pass `result` directly to `sqlite.save`, like `scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys=['id'], data=result)`?

Comment: @Wilduck The reason I have the error handling is because, if you look for example at graph.facebook.com/3, this page contains no user data and so I don't want to collate this info and skip to the next user, ie. no 4 etc...

Comment: You can handle that error specifically without handling all possible errors. (What if somewhere in this code you misspelled a variable name? You would never find out, since the entire block would be skipped).

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on what is wrong with this code?

Yes. You are swallowing all of your errors. There could be a huge number of things going wrong in the block under `try`. If anything goes wrong in that block, you move on without printing anything.

You should only ever use a `try` / `except` block when you are looking to handle a specific error.

modify your code so that it looks like this:

```
while True:
    profile_id +=1
    profile_url = urlparse.urljoin(source_url, str(profile_id))
    results_json = simplejson.loads(scraperwiki.scrape(profile_url))
    for result in results_json['results']:
        print result
        data = {}
        # ... more ...
```

and then you will get detailed error messages when specific things go wrong.

As for your concern in the comments:

> The reason I have the error handling is because, if you look for
>   example at graph.facebook.com/3, this page contains no user data and
>   so I don't want to collate this info and skip to the next user, ie. no
>   4 etc

If you want to handle the case where there is no data, then find a way to handle that case specifically. It is bad practice to swallow all errors.

Comment: Thanks @wilduck. When reviewing the response in Python, the actual error returned for the non-relevant pages is a HTTPError (400 - Bad Request). Therefore, I suppose I could handle the HTTPError?

Comment: That sounds like a good way to go. Also, you should try to have as little as possible in your `try` blocks. You might also want to use the except block to log which `ids` are not returning anything.